# Compose rounded Button with transparent background

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to display a `Button` with rounded corners and a 50% transparent background. My current attempt looks like this:

```
MaterialTheme {
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        color = Color.Yellow
    ) {
        Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)) {
            Button(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .clip(CircleShape),
                onClick = { },
                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = Color.White.copy(alpha = 0.5f))
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "My Button",
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result is not very pretty:

[image]

It looks like the issue is with with the shading, but I'm not sure how to remove it and just show the same color within the whole shape.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out the shadow will disappear when the elevation is removed.

```
Button(
    modifier = Modifier
        .clip(CircleShape),
    onClick = { },
    elevation = null,
    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = Color.White.copy(alpha = 0.5f))
) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Button is just a `Surface` wrapping the content that you provide. You could check the source. So, I just tweaked it a little

```
@Composable
fun HollowButton(
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
    elevation: ButtonElevation? = ButtonDefaults.elevation(),
    shape: Shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
    border: BorderStroke? = null,
    colors: ButtonColors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(),
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = ButtonDefaults.ContentPadding,
    content: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit
) {
    val contentColor by colors.contentColor(enabled)
    Surface(
        modifier = modifier,
        shape = shape,
        color = colors.backgroundColor(enabled).value.copy(0.5f), //Basically I refactored the alpha modification to here
        contentColor = contentColor.copy(alpha = 1f),
        border = border,
        elevation = elevation?.elevation(enabled, interactionSource)?.value ?: 0.dp,
        onClick = onClick,
        enabled = enabled,
        role = Role.Button,
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
        indication = rememberRipple()
    ) {
        CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides contentColor.alpha) {
            ProvideTextStyle(
                value = MaterialTheme.typography.button
            ) {
                Row(
                    Modifier
                        .defaultMinSize(
                            minWidth = ButtonDefaults.MinWidth,
                            minHeight = ButtonDefaults.MinHeight
                        )
                        .padding(contentPadding),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                    content = content
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: Ah, stupid me didn't even click into this code. Thanks a lot. There is actually an even easier solution that I found thanks to you. Just set the button elevation to zero or pass a `null` elevation: `Button(elevation = null, ...) {}`

Comment: Yeah this is the exact same approach I would go about taking, but I got confused because of the fact that the parameter was of type `ButtonElevation`. My mind did not go towards assigning `null` to it. It's funny sometimes